# How to expose service outside k8s cluster?

Tags: kubernetes

I have run a Hello World application using the below command.

`kubectl run hello-world --replicas=2 --labels="run=load-balancer-example" --image=gcr.io/google-samples/node-hello:1.0  --port=8080`

Created a service as below

`kubectl expose deployment hello-world --type=NodePort --name=example-service`

The pods are running

```
NAME                          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
hello-world-68ff65cf7-dn22t   1/1     Running   0          2m20s
hello-world-68ff65cf7-llvjt   1/1     Running   0          2m20s
```

Service:

```
NAME              TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
example-service   NodePort    10.XX.XX.XX     <none>        8080:32023/TCP   66s
```

Here, I am able to test it through curl inside the cluster.

```
curl http://10.XX.XX.XX:8080
Hello Kubernetes!
```

How can I access this service outside my cluster? (example, through laptop browser)

Comment: Would you read an official documentation before posting it on Stack? - https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/expose/expose-intro/  https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateless-application/expose-external-ip-address/

Answer (score 2):

you shoud try

http://IP_OF_KUBERNETES:32023

IP_OF_KUBERNETES can be your master IP your worker IP
when you expose a port in kubernetes .It expose that port in all of your server in cluster.Imagine you have two worker node with IP1 and IP2
and one pode is running in IP1  and in worker2 there is no pods but you can access your pod by

http://IP1:32023

http://IP2:32023

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to access it outside the cluster using NodePort assingned(32023). Please paste following `http://<IP>:<Port>` in your browser and you will able to access your app:

```
http://<MASTER/WORKER_IP>:32023
```

Comment: he should not use 10.xx.xx.xx.it is accessible from in side

Comment: Yes, you're right it is clusterIP not MasterIP. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are answers already provided, but I felt like this topic needed some consolidation.

This seems to be fairly easy. NodePort actually exposes your application as the name says on the port of each node. So all you have to do is just find the IP address of the Node on which the pod is. You can do it by running:
`kubectl get pods -o wide` so you can find the IP or name of the node on which the pod is, then just follow what previous answers state: so  `http://<MASTER/WORKER_IP>:PORT`

There is more methods: 
You can deploy Ingress Controller and configure [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#what-is-ingress) so the application will be reachable through the internet.

You can also use `kubectl proxy` to expose ClusterIP service outside of the cluster. Like in this example with [Dashboard](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/web-ui-dashboard/#accessing-the-dashboard-ui).

Another way is to use [LoadBalancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer) type, which requires underlying cloud infrastructure.

If you are using minikube you can try to run `minikube service list` to check your exposed services and their IP.

Answer (score 0):

You can access your service using MasterIP or WorkerIP. If you are planning to use it in production or in a more reliable way you should create a service with `type LoadBalancer`. And use load balancers IP to access it.

If you are using any cloud env, make sure the firewall rules allow incoming traffic.

This will take care of redirecting request to which ever node the pod is running on. Else you will have to manually hit masterIP or workerIP depending on where the pod is running. If the pod gets moved to different node, you will have to change the ip you are hitting

[Service Load Balancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer)