# how to access service on rpi k8s cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I built a k8s cluster with help of this guide: [rpi+k8s](https://wiki.learnlinux.tv/index.php/How_to_build_your_own_Raspberry_Pi_Kubernetes_Cluster). I got some basic nginx service up and running and and I can curl from master node to worker node to get the nginx welcome page content using:

```
k exec nginx-XXX-XXX -it -- curl localhost:80
```

I tried following suggestions in the following SO posts:

[link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62585798/k8s-how-do-i-access-my-app-with-a-service)
[link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55605975/how-to-expose-service-outside-k8s-cluster)

However, I still can't access a simple nginx service on the worker node from my local computer (linux). I used, `NODE IP:NODE PORT`. I also installed kubefwd and ran, `sudo kubefwd svc -n nginx-ns` but I don't see the expected output where it would show the port forwards. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Output:

```
NAME                TYPE       CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
service/nginx-svc   NodePort   10.101.19.230   <none>        80:32749/TCP   168m

NAME                    READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/nginx   3/3     3            3           168m

NAME                               DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/nginx-54485b444f   3         3         3       168m
```

And here is the yaml file:

```
kind: Namespace
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: nginx-ns
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx
  namespace: nginx-ns
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx 
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx 
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx 
        image: nginx:1.19-alpine
        ports:
        - name: nginxport
          containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-svc
  namespace: nginx-ns
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    name: nginxport
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    nodePort: 32749
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: backend
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your service `nginx-svc` where you have used two `selector`.

remove below part:

```
  selector:
    app: backend
```

Updated `service.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-svc
  namespace: nginx-ns
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    name: nginxport
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    nodePort: 32749
  type: NodePort
```

Then, Try this one for port-forwarding.

```
kubectl port-forward -n nginx-ns svc/nginx-svc 8080:80
```

Template is like this:

`kubectl port-forward -n <namespace> svc/<svc_name> <local_port>:<svc_port>`

Then try in the browser with `127.0.0.1:8080` or `localhost:8080`

Comment: hi, thanks for your suggestion! I didn't get a notification thus the late reply. Anyways, when I tried the port-forward command as you wrote above, I get this: ```Unable to listen on port 80: Listeners failed to create with the following errors: [unable to create listener: Error listen tcp4 127.0.0.1:80: bind: permission denied unable to create listener: Error listen tcp6 [::1]:80: bind: permission denied]
error: unable to listen on any of the requested ports: [{80 80}]
```

Comment: I then tried `kubectl port-forward -n nginx-ns svc/nginx-svc 32749:80` and i get the output: ```Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:32749 -> 80
Forwarding from [::1]:32749 -> 80```. Is this correct? I want port 32749 to be forwarded to 80? However when I go into my browser, and type in the <NODE_IP>:32749, I still get `Unable to connect`.

Comment: I have updated my ans . Can you try now plz? `nodeIP` will not work outside cluster. so `<NODE_IP>:32749` will not work. @SpencerTrinh

Comment: hi @H.R. Emon. thanks for quick response. I did try what you suggested. This is the output from the `port-forward` command: ```Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:8080 -> 80
Forwarding from [::1]:8080 -> 80
```. When I go into my browser and type: `localhost:8080` I still get `Unable to connect, problem loading page` I tried both 127.0.0.1 and localhost. Does this issue have to do anything with my router setup? My laptop is connected to router on wifi, and the rpi's are connected thru a switch that is connected to the router.

Comment: @SpencerTrinh i don't see any problem with your port-forwarding `Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:8080 -> 80 Forwarding from [::1]:8080 -> 80` . do you have terminated the command prompt after running the command? you need to leave the terminal as it is. then try in the browser. don't terminate the port forwarding command.

Comment: yeah, i did leave that terminal pane open and left it running. I did not press `Ctrl+c`. Maybe some other config i need to do? I didn't set static ip on the rpi.

Comment: can you  share `kubectl get endpoints -n nginx-ns` the output of this command please? @SpencerTrinh

Comment: ```NAME        ENDPOINTS                                      AGE
nginx-svc   10.244.0.23:80,10.244.0.27:80,10.244.0.28:80   7h42m
```

Comment: can you try with static ip ? [link](https://limpygnome.com/2019/09/21/raspberry-pi-kubernetes-cluster/)

Comment: i think in rpi the issue is for static ip.

Comment: or can you try with other service type. i mean with `clusterIp` service type. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/#creating-a-service

Comment: thanks @H.R. Emon. I will try static ip and iptables when I get a chance. Appreciate the responses :)